# Bibtex creating subitems when not asked?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've been struggling to slowly add references with bibtex to my documents. I created this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\cite{Boulos}
\cite{Lawson}

\end{document}
```

And here is the `.bib` file's contents:

```
@book{Boulos,
author    = "BOULOS, Paulo",
title     = "C\'{a}lculo Diferencial e Integral",
publisher = "Pearson Makron Books",
volume   = "1",
address  = "S\~{a}o Paulo",
edition  = "1",
year      = "1999",
note     = "380 p",
}

@book{Lawson,
author    = "LAWSON, Terry",
title     = "\'{A}lgebra Linear",
publisher = "Edgard Bl{\"u}cher ltda",  
address  = "S\~{a}o Paulo",
edition  = "1",
year      = "1996",
note     = "348 p",
}
```

This produces, in the references section:
[image: Notice the subitems below the second reference]

How to get rid of those subitem looking things below?

Comment: Those are your citations! Did you perhaps want `\nocite{Boulos, Lawson}`?

Comment: You are right! I was confused because it produced the reference and the citation at the same time! Is it possible that the citation's text uses the author's name instead of numbers? Like "[Boulos]" instead of "[1]"?

Comment: this is done by the bibliographystyle and maybe an extra package.

Comment: But if you really are just starting, i think `biblatex` would be the better thing to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are from your citations: they have to correspond to a bibliography somewhere.

Comment: My apologies for forgetting to accept the answer a long time ago! Adjusted it now!